# Wildfly 27 : @Schedule/Weld is not working so Schedulers not running where it is running on wildfly 17

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-26, wildfly-16, wildfly-27

@Schedule not working
Earlier i have worked with Wildfly 16 and our code looks like :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;    
import javax.ejb.AccessTimeout;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout;

@Singleton
@AccessTimeout(value = 4, unit = TimeUnit.HOURS)
@TransactionTimeout(value = 4, unit = TimeUnit.HOURS)
public class BankingSchedulerTest {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BankingSchedulerTest.class.getName());
    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/2", persistent = false)
    public void ServiceNowMscSchedularApplication() {
        LOG.info("Hello world !! Banking Scheduler test");
    }
}
```

Project structure contains:
\src\main\webapp\META-INF\singleton-deployment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<singleton-deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:singleton-deployment:1.0"/>
```

and pom file contains:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.integrator</groupId>
        <artifactId>integrator-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.integrator</groupId>
    <artifactId>banking-schduler-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Banking test scheduler</name>
    <description>Banking test scheduler</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Issue in Deployment**:

When i deploy this code in wildfly 27 then it gives:

```
    2023-08-09 08:13:38,759 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
    2023-08-09 08:13:38,790 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 89) WFLYCLINF0002: Started default cache from server container
    2023-08-09 08:13:38,872 INFO  [org.wildfly.clustering.singleton.server] (LegacyDistributedSingletonService - 1) WFLYCLSN0003: BNKAP08:batch-01 elected as the singleton provider of the jboss.deployment.unit."banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".installer service
    2023-08-09 08:13:38,872 INFO  [org.wildfly.clustering.singleton.server] (LegacyDistributedSingletonService - 1) WFLYCLSN0001: This node will now operate as the singleton provider of the jboss.deployment.unit."banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".installer service
    2023-08-09 08:13:38,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 90) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
    2023-08-09 08:13:39,083 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 97) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT' for server 'default-server'
```

When i deploy in my old wildfly 16 then i get following:

```
2023-08-09 10:25:53,369 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name: "banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
2023-08-09 10:25:53,371 INFO  [org.wildfly.clustering.server] (LegacyDistributedSingletonService - 1) WFLYCLSV0003: alt-esb-app01:masterdata-batch-01 elected as the singleton provider of the jboss.deployment.unit."banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".installer service
2023-08-09 10:25:53,372 INFO  [org.wildfly.clustering.server] (LegacyDistributedSingletonService - 1) WFLYCLSV0001: This node will now operate as the singleton provider of the jboss.deployment.unit."banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".installer service
2023-08-09 10:25:53,421 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
2023-08-09 10:25:53,442 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'BankingSchedulerTest' in deployment unit 'deployment "banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"' are as follows:
        java:global/banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/BankingSchedulerTest!com.integrator.banking.BankingSchedulerTest
        java:app/banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/BankingSchedulerTest!com.integrator.banking.BankingSchedulerTest
        java:module/BankingSchedulerTest!com.integrator.banking.BankingSchedulerTest
        ejb:banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/BankingSchedulerTest!com.integrator.banking.BankingSchedulerTest
        java:global/banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/BankingSchedulerTest
        java:app/banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/BankingSchedulerTest
        java:module/BankingSchedulerTest
2023-08-09 10:25:53,668 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 88) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT' for server 'default-server'
2023-08-09 10:25:53,766 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "banking-schduler-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")
2023-08-09 10:26:00,002 INFO  [com.integrator.BankingSchedulerTest] (EJB default - 2) Hello world !! Banking Scheduler test
```

Can anyone suggest what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

WildFly 27 is Jakarta EE 10. You cannot use the `javax.*` variant, Jakarta EE 8, dependencies when deploying to WildFly 27. You need to migrate your application to Jakarta EE 10 or use the [deployment-transformer-feature-pack](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/deployment-transformer-feature-pack) which will transform your bytecode to use the new namespace during deployment. Note though you will not be able to use any new Jakarta EE 10 features and depending on what API's you use, some things may not work.